# how do I get the true labels when I use a ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory

Tags: keras

I have a code running where as data input I have two numpy array (X_train,y_true). I like the data augmentation of the ImageDataGenerator.

Can I use this for getting corresponding numpy arrays?

Here is some code:

```python
train_data_dir="Path to directory containing for each class a directory of images"

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                         horizontal_flip=True,
                         rotation_range=360)
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
       train_data_dir,
       target_size=(img_width, img_height),
       batch_size=22,
       class_mode=None,
       shuffle=True)

x=generator.next()
```

Now x a a np.array, containing images of both my classes. Can I find the corresponding array with labels somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's quite simple. A generator must output both x and y:

```
x, y = generator.next()
```

Another option depending on your python:

```
x, y = next(generator)
```

**Your generator is not returning any Y, though**, because you used `class_mode=None`.

You should use one of these to make the generator produce labels:

- categorical
- binary
- sparse

Usually, for a multiclass purpose, you'd go with "categorical". For one class (yes/no), use a "binary".

Comment: Thanks, I tried both, but in both cases I got:  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Ah, you're using `class_mode=None`. This prevents the generator from producing the Y part. (Updated the answer).

Comment: Great :) -- If you think this answers your question, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried it and it worked! Now I understand why I'm receiving an error when I use `class_mode=binary`